# How can find I the place where the Screaming Frog found a link on my site?

Tags: seo, seo-audit, screaming-frog

I use screaming frog for my site. For some URLs it finds I don't know where it found those links.

This is an example image of my screaming frog:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's in the "crawl path" report.

I found it via
the third point in this article: [10 Features In The SEO Spider You Should Really Know | Screaming Frog](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/10-features/)